# Require.js -- how to load relative to a module directory

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dynamic-script-loading

My structure looks like so:

- index.html
- main.js #holds the configs.path and configs.shim
- libs

  - jquery.js
  - require.js
  - backbone.js
  - underscore.js
- modules

  - app

    - main.js  **#want to load in ./views/app.js here**
    - views

      - app.js

so in /modules/app/main.js, I want to load in the /modules/app/views/app.js but having problem

Here is /modules/app/main.js

```
define(['views/app'],function(App){
console.log('app main')
//var app = new App();
})
```

The console error message  I get is Get failed with path `GitProjects/GameApp/views/app.js`

How do I get it to load relatively inside modules?

here is `./main.js` the file that holds the configs

```
require.config({
    paths: {
      jquery: './libs/jquery-2.0.3',
      underscore: './libs/underscore',
      backbone: './libs/backbone'
    },
    shim: {
        "underscore": {
            exports: '_'
        },
        "backbone": {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        }
    }
});
```

and here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stop Game App</title>
        <script src="./libs/require.js" data-main='./main'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script>
        require(['./modules/app/main'],function(){
                console.log('main')
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want ./ to the path

Comment: nice thanks. I tried that before and it didn't work, maybe cache didn't update or something. Now it seems to work. Thanks a bunch. If you want to convert the comment into an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the path to "./" and be relative. That's all there is to it.